# SQL server mismach columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query for SQL Server.

1. must sum two separate columns
2. if the column `Debe` is less than the column `Haber` should print "mismatch"

The explanation is :

- There are two tables `ContD` and `Cont` with a common column `ID`
- The table `ContD` has two important columns, `Debe` and `Haber`.
- The table `Cont` has one important column,  `Importe`

If the sum of `Debe` is not equal to the sum of `Haber` should report printing a message on another column.

If the final number `Debe` and `Haber` are equal, compared to the column `Importe` of the table `Cont` and print coincidence in another column

http://www.grupoalta.com/wp-content/uploads/queryconciliacion.png

Comment: please create schema and data sample in sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

**Note:** I have commented the script that you actually want to use, the uncommented script is a quick sample that I have made out of the screenshot you shared, but as [@Horaciux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3564751/horaciux) said, please, include a sample the next time.

**Note 2:** I supposed that the id in your table Cont is the primary key or it is just Unique, meanwhile the id in the table contD is a foreign key or it just doesn't have the constraint of Uniqueness.

```
DECLARE @t1 AS TABLE (id NUMERIC,debe DECIMAL(18,2),haber DECIMAL(18,2))
DECLARE @t2 AS TABLE (id NUMERIC,importe DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT 10887,NULL,603.2 UNION ALL
SELECT 10887,83.2,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10887,520,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10888,NULL,21.344 UNION ALL
SELECT 10888,18.40,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 10888,2.944,NULL

INSERT INTO @t2
SELECT 10887,603.2 UNION ALL
SELECT 10888,150

SELECT  id
    ,SUM(debe) 'Debe'
    ,SUM(haber) 'Haber'
    ,(SELECT importe FROM @t2 where id=t1.id) 'Importe'
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(debe)=SUM(haber) THEN '' ELSE 'not equal' END 'Debe=Haber'
    ,CASE WHEN (SUM(debe)=SUM(haber) AND (SELECT importe FROM @t2 WHERE id=t1.id)=SUM(debe)) THEN 'Coincidence' ELSE '' END 'Debe=Haber=Importe'
FROM @t1 t1
GROUP BY id

/*
SELECT  id
    ,SUM(debe) 'Debe'
    ,SUM(haber) 'Haber'
    ,(SELECT importe FROM @t2 where id=t1.id) 'Importe'
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(debe)<>SUM(haber) THEN 'not equal' ELSE '' END 'Debe=Haber'
    ,CASE WHEN (SUM(debe)=SUM(haber) AND (SELECT importe FROM cont WHERE id=t1.id)=SUM(debe)) THEN 'Coincidence' ELSE '' END 'Debe=Haber=Importe'
FROM contd t1
GROUP BY id
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach that does the comparison and returns one value, depending on the nature of the match.  This uses a `case` statement:

```
select cd.id,
       (case when cd.sumdebe <> cd.sumhaber then 'not equals'
             when cd.sumdebe = c.importe then 'all same'
             else 'mismatch'
        end)
from (select id, sum(debe) as sumdebe, sum(haber) as sumhaber
      from contd
      group by id
     ) cd left outer join
     cont c
     on cd.id = c.id;
```